# Cannot Remove Event Listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i tried to remove the event click event listener from a button.

In my real problem i have multiple scroolbars synced (whenever one changes the other scrolls to the same position) and i want to remove the onscroll event.

I oversimplified the example, but does not work. Any idea?

```
import { useRef } from "react";

var btnRef;

function clicked(){
    alert('btn clicked');
    if(btnRef.current){
        console.log('remove click listener ...')
        btnRef.current.removeEventListener('click', clicked);
    }
}

function MyComponent(){

    btnRef = useRef();

    return (
        <button ref={btnRef} onClick={clicked}>click me</button>
    );

}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Don't use this approach. Have a state that determines whether the button should be disabled or not, and then set the `disabled` attribute on the button.

Answer (score 2):

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
```

set clicked to true on button click, add logic to display based on boolean value

Answer (score 0):

You need to use state and update it when the button is clicked for the first time, so whenever the button is clicked again, do nothing

```
function MyComponent(){
  const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false)

  function handleClick(){
      if(clicked){
        return undefiend
      }
      setClicked(true)
      alert('btn clicked');
  }

    return (
        <button disabled={clicked} onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
    );

}
export default MyComponent;
```